# Php header url redirect and htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, header, location

I’m confused about apache RewriteRule in htaccess. I have hundreds of `header('Location: script_name.php');` in my webapp and would like to make url’s more user friendly (not SEO friendly as search engines won’t be allowed to crawl the app). Here's a typical piece of code :

```
if(isset($_POST['get_product']))
{
    // PHP/PDO code here
    header('Location: product_catalog_detail.php?with or without query strings');
}
```

that gives :

```
http://localhost/smart_entreprise/folder1/folder2/product_catalog_detail?catID=1&productID=1
```

Now I'd like to keep this URL server-side and show the user this for all script names beginning with `product_catalog` :

```
http://localhost/smart_entreprise/folder1/folder2/catalog
```

or even better :

```
http://localhost/smart_entreprise/catalog
```

Doest it makes sense ? Thanks.

Comment: which framework you are using for this?

Comment: no framework, just plain PHP

Comment: you can create a page catalog.php and send the catID & productID in Temp SESSION or in POST, by clicking the details button of the product. and then remove .php extension using .HTACCESS

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will investigate renaming the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/webroot/.htaccess
RewriteRule ^smart_entreprise\/(\w+)$ product_catalog_detail.php?catID=$1
```

Please see

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: merci pour la doc.